# How to show/hide the Navigator (not NavigatorIOS) dynamically

Tags: react-native, navigator

I have an idea that there is only one Navigator in app. So I need show/hide the navigator dynamically. Maybe the idea is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've really understood the usage of Navigator. Here's [a navigator demo](https://github.com/h87kg/NavigatorDemo)